# Get selected value from custom dropdown component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular2-forms

I am working on an Angular 2 project. I have created a dropdown component as follows:

```
 @Component({
    selector: 'dropdown',
    template: ` <div class="row" >
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
   <select  class="form-control" placeholder="--select--" >
      <option 
        *ngFor="let value of values" (click)="selectItem(value.value)">{{value.text}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>`
})

export class DropdownComponent {
    @Input()
    values: Array<DropdownValue>;

    @Output()
    select: EventEmitter<any>;

    constructor() {
        this.select = new EventEmitter();
        this.values = new Array<DropdownValue>();
    }

    selectItem(value) {
        this.select.emit(value);
    }
}
```

and used in my other component

```
<dropdown [values]="categories" (select)="onselect($event)"></dropdown>
```

but I failed to access the selected value of my dropdown list in component class.

If I use `<u><li>` for dropdown creation, it hits the method `onselect()` but I want to create dropdown list using `<select><option>...` - is there any way to access the selected value?

```
 export class AssetComponent
{
    public categories: DropdownValue[] = [
        { "value": 1, "text": "Table" },
        { "value": 2, "text": "Chair" },
        { "value": 3, "text": "Light" }
    ];
    public isCollapsedContent: boolean = false;

    searchfilter(): void {
        this.isCollapsedContent = !this.isCollapsedContent;
        console.log("collapsed happen");
    }
    onselect(value:any): void
    {
        console.log(value)
    }
}
```

I want to access value of dropdown on button click

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="searchfilter()">
    Search here
</button>
```

Comment: Your event is triggered or not ? as I suggest please add a model to your select and on `ngModelChange` try to emit your event don't do it on option click

Comment: but it will give me text of dropdown what if i want to access value

Comment: what do you mean by text of drop down ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `change` event on the `select` element:

```
<select  (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)" class="form-control" placeholder="--select--" >
```

Get the selected value into a method, and emit the value to an `@Output` property:

```
onSelect(val) {
    this.select.emit(val)
}
```

And now you can get the selected value from the dropdown component:

```
<dropdown [values]="categories" (select)="onselect($event)"></dropdown>
```

Don't forget to import `Output` from `@angular/core` and include the output property to your component:

```
@Output select
```

Comment: i have tried this but it gives text value of dropdown what if i want to acess its value field

Comment: You don't have a value field in your options. Add value="{{ value.value }}" and you should get its value instead of the text.

Comment: Ok great, then you can mark the answer as accepted. If you solved it on you own you can write that solution down and accept that. It will help other people experiencing similar problems.